# Enable Ambient Occlusion (AO) in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

**How do I enable Ambient Occlusion (AO) in Cycles?**
In Eevee, I just active AO in the render settings, but there's no option to do this in Cycles?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution: You don't need to enable Ambient Occlusion in the "World"-settings (since this just brightens your image): just enable it in the "View Layer"-settings as a pass. Then, in the Compositor, add a Color Balance node (or some other color node that allows you to change the darkness of the AO pass) and connect it to the AO output of the Render Layers node. Then, connect the output of the Color Balance node and the Image output of the Render Layers node to a Multiply (Mix) node, and then finally connect the output of the Multiply (Mix) node to a File Output node. This way you can manually control the AO in Cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's in the World Settings context tab (red planet icon).

Comment: This does add Ambient Occlusion to Cycles' renders too, right? Not just the viewport?

Comment: But wait, why does enabling Ambient Occlusion in the World Settings (red planet icon) make the image brighter? It even seems to have less Ambient Occlusion after enabling Ambient Occlusion in the World Settings...?

Comment: The AO calculation is for how much light is being occluded and (apparently) reflected by surfaces as well. Try playing with the Distance parameter. Yes, it contributes to the final render.

Comment: This setting [doesn't exist](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/r744dq/wheres_ambient_occlusion_in_blender_30_cycles/) in 3.0+